# UINavigationController and Back button title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, viewcontroller

Looks like the Back button of UINavigationBar uses view controller's title as its title, and if the previous view controller does not have a title, it uses Back, but is there a way to customise the title of the back button, no matter what title does previous view controller has?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create your own bar button item and assign it to the previous view controller *navigationItem backBarButtonItem* property, for example:

```
UIBarButtonItem *temporaryBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
temporaryBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"MAIN", @"Back bar button item to go back to the main view controller");
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = temporaryBarButtonItem;
```

Check the [UINavigationItem class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/backBarButtonItem) to make sure you put the codes above in the correct view controller, especially this part:

> When this navigation item is immediately **below the top item in the
>   stack**, the navigation controller derives the back button for the
>   navigation bar from this navigation item.